# How to delete disjunction rows of two larget tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

table products1:  30 mio rows
table products2: 100 mio rows

Both tables are different, but share a common unique index:

```
create table products1(
    ...
    UNIQUE KEY uniq_products (name, manufacture, releasedate,... <a total of 10 fields> )
)
```

I want to remove all rows from table1, whose unique index does not occur in table2.

I started as follows:

```
DELETE FROM products1 p1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM products2 p2 WHERE p1.name = p2.name, p1.manufacture = p2.manufacture, ...
)
```

Question: is this the correct approach in general? How can I speed up queries like this due to the large dataset?

Comment: Are these tables in Production and being written actively ? If no, then better option *may be* to create a new table; copy the required data into that new table; rename it to original table, while renaming original table to something else; check everything works and then drop the (renamed) original table.

Comment: If the tables are actively written, but the table `products1` is MyISAM. In that case, you can look at `DELETE QUICK ..`. This will speed up things a bit, as index rebuild does not happen alongside delete operation. Once the deletion is done, you can run `OPTIMIZE TABLE` at off-peak hours, to reclaim the space.

Answer (score 1):

Your `delete` appears to do what you want, assuming that `,` really means `AND`. And it is a reasonable query.

For this query:

```
DELETE p1 FROM products1 p1
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM products2 p2
                       WHERE p1.name = p2.name AND
                             p1.manufacture = p2.manufacture AND
                      );
```

You want an index on the comparison keys:  `products2(name, manufacture, . . . )`.  You already have this index, if the combination of 10 keys is declared unique *and you are using all 10 columns with equality comparisons*.

Note that if you are removing a large number of rows -- hundreds of thousands or more -- then the overhead of the `delete` is going to have a big impact on performance.  You might want to create a new table with the rows you want (essentially based on the above logic).  Then truncate the original table and re-insert the rows.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest two ways

1. In the way you suggested, first disable or delete indexes and then enable them
2. Create a heap table with columns of products1 and paste the shared data, and then paste the clustered index and other indexes into it. Delete the original table and rename the new table

Good luck